# I cannot start mysql.server in the Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mysql

Ubuntu's version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I'm having problems for start to mysql, always that I trying appears the next message:

```
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I tried check the `mysqld.log` using the command `tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log`, but there doesn't appear to be one.

So I tried to check with `systemctl status mysql.service` and appears this:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-06-07 11:56:52 -03; 5h 18min ago
       Docs: man:mysqld(8)
             http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
    Process: 8885 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
jun 07 11:56:52 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
jun 07 11:56:52 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 11:56:52 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jun 07 11:56:52 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 07 11:56:52 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

My `mysql.cnf` file is configured like this:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
#  IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#


!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/ 
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Further I tried install and after remove the MySQL APT Repository, but this message appears:

```
Error while installing package: the subprocess installed, package mysql-common, script post-installation return the error status exit 2
```

Output of the command `sudo journalctl -u mysql.service -n 100`:

```
-- Logs begin at Sat 2021-01-09 07:11:57 -03, end at Mon 2021-06-07 17:52:46 -03. --
jun 07 10:37:25 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
jun 07 10:37:25 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 mysql-systemd-start[73897]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf>
jun 07 10:37:25 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
jun 07 10:37:25 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 07 10:37:25 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 mysql-systemd-start[73936]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf>
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 4.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 mysql-systemd-start[73975]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf>
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILU>
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
jun 07 10:37:26 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Reboot --
jun 07 11:56:50 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
```

The command `sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log` not return anything

How can I fix this?

Comment: Include the output of `sudo journalctl -u mysql.service -n 100` please, as it will provide more useful information than `systemctl -l status` will

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the following: (1) the version of Ubuntu you are using (2) the tail end of the MySQL log: `sudo tail -f /var/log/mysql/error.log` (3) did MySQL work for you yesterday?

Comment: No, Mysql don't works yesterday. Actually don't work not once

Comment: How did you install MySQL Server? This error message is pointing to an easy-to-check issue: `MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: Actually installed LAMP first, then I install phpmyadmin and when I went to do login, appear this error `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`. So I went to check the mysql and it was already installed, but not started. I saw this issue, I try to set up the mysql.cnf, but error continued

Comment: How should it be configured?? Because the directory is correct, only configuration is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is clearly stated in the output:

```
jun 07 10:37:25 mauriciojr27-Inspiron-3442 mysql-systemd-start[73897]: MySQL configuration not found at /etc/mysql/my.cnf>
```

Your system tries to use `my.cnf` and you provided `mysql.cnf`.
Try to copy `mysql.cnf` to `my.cnf` and restart.

Comment: Thanks, this solve the problem!!

Comment: @Mauriciojr27 Ok, glad to see it helped.  Could you mark the answer as 'Accepted'?  This will allow other users to find it more easily.